# Use return statement twice in factory

Tags: angularjs, return, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have a factory code where I need to `return methods` for use in template and also `return _this` for use in getting info from the controller to send off via the factory.
  Problem is I don't know how to put both at the same time as the `return` picks the first `return`. How do I add both?
Code:

```
.factory('chatroomService', function($websocket,$rootScope,$state) {
    var dataStream = $websocket('ws://localhost:9000');
    _this = this;
    var collection = ["Ola"];
    dataStream.onOpen(function() {
      _this.sendChat = function(data) {
        dataStream.send(data);
      };
    });
  var methods = {
    collection : collection,
    get: function() {
      dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({action: 'get'}));
    }
  };
    return methods; //problem here
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return an object with both

```
return {methods: methods, context: _this}
```

And to use it you'll call `chatroomService.methods` or `chatroomService.context`

Comment: @Olli What's not working about it? In your controller console log chatroomService. What does it show?

Comment: log of chatroomService: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: stringified log of chatroomService: chatroom st [{"collection":["Ola"]},{}]

Comment: stringified log of chatroomService:  [{"collection":["Ola"]},{}]

Comment: ok so the methods object is making it in there. You should be able to use it by doing chatroomService[0].collection. I suggest using the object solution and you'll be able to do chatroomService.methods.collection. Now you need to figure out why _this isn't working. put console.log(_this) right above your return and see what it's trying to return.